# Any way to speed up Python long int bitwise operation?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a chess program in Python and I use [python-chess](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-chess) for board representation and move generation etc. It is generally very good and has very useful functionalities.

However, since it is in pure Python, it is now the bottleneck of my AI. Python long integer and its bitwise operations are extensively used in the module eg

```
x = b & -b
b ^= x

if not x & 0xffffffff:
    x >>= 32
    r |= 32
```

Is there anyway to speed up this kind of operation in Python, by some other module maybe? Is it possible without rewriting in C or Fortran? I tried [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) package, but it doesn't seem to be able to compile python long int.

Many thanks.

Comment: have you looked at cython, numpy f2py etc..?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I can write only very basic C/Fortran, so would like to see first if it's possible to do without myself writing them.

Comment: You don't have to write c  to use cython, that is the point it does all the work for you.

Comment: Use PyPy. Or, if possible, use Numpy.

Comment: @Veedrac, I tried numpy earlier, not faster. Numpy is good for array operation, here the board is represented in one long int.

Comment: @Veedrac How does PyPy help with bit operations? (I'm actually asking)

Comment: PyPy uses just-in-time compilation, so it executes machine code, not CPython byte code.

Comment: is there a reason why you chose bitwise scheme - it seems that many other representations might be more efficient in terms of speed.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 As the OP states in the question, it is *the module* that is implemented that way, not the OP's code. As the writer of `python-chess`.

Comment: If it's the bottleneck, maybe there something wrong with your approach...

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I think bitboard is the most used chess representation because of its speed. What other representations would you suggest? (I mean in general, not python specific. I probably still need a python module which implements that way)

Comment: @jf328 - I have never tried to write a chess program, but if i did, I wouldn't start with a bitmap. If i was writing in python i would accept that at best I have a sparse array (it is impossible for all squares to be populated) so I would start with something that supported that easily (like a dictionary), but I do accept that once you get deep into the design if you are doing a lot of look forwards, then that could get memory expensive. Clearly speed is a problem here though - so speed can't be the only reason a bitmap is used.

Answer (score 3):

I maintain the [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) library and it supports integer operations that are usually faster than Python's native integers.

Here is a quick example:

```
In [3]: x=12345678901234567890
In [4]: %timeit y=x;y>>=32
10000000 loops, best of 3: 113 ns per loop
In [5]: x=gmpy2.mpz(x)
In [6]: %timeit y=x;y>>=32
10000000 loops, best of 3: 71.9 ns per loop
```

The `mpz` type behaves almost identically to Python long so it should be a direct replacement. `gmpy2` also supports a mutable integer type called `xmpz`. It supports direct bit manipulation and may be faster for inplace operations.

```
In [9]: x=gmpy2.xmpz(0)
In [10]: bin(x)
Out[10]: '0b0'
In [11]: x[4]=1
In [12]: bin(x)
Out[12]: '0b10000'
```

To use all the performance benefits of the `xmpz` type, you may need to modify your logic and/or code.

Comment: interestingly, the python-chess author says exactly this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray

It's a Python interface to C code, that is designed to speed-up bit-wise operations.

Comment: It's slower on CPython by a factor of 5.